# \def macro with multiple parameters

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm trying to tweak a style file, I have a 'def' as follows:

```
\def\logo#1{\gdef\@logo{#1}} \gdef\@logo{}
```

Inside of a custom 'make title':

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\@logo}
```

I'm new to Tex/Macros, I was just wondering how I can add the scale parameter to the 'logo' def macro? i.e. I'd like to fully parameterise the call to `\includegraphics`.

Edit:
As per below, I've added the logo into the 'maketitle', on a simple style, not sure if there is a better way to do that?

```
\newcommand{\logo}[2][]{%
  \gdef\make@logo{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\let\make@logo\relax

%% title
\def\@maketitle
   {
   \clearpage
   \vskip -3em

   \ifx\make@logo\relax
   \else
    \make@logo
   \fi

   \newpage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{-24pt}
    \begin{center}
      {\Large \bf \@title \par}\vspace*{24pt}{
        \lineskip 1em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            \@author \\
            \vspace*{1pt}\
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \vskip 1em
      \vspace*{12pt}
    \end{center}
   }
```

Comment: Could you show what you mean by "fully parameterise"?

Comment: I mean, \logo{my-pic.png} will mean \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{my-pic.png} will get called in my 'maketitle'. I'd like to be able to specify the scale parameter too, i.e. \logo[0.7]{my-pic.png} thanks --Mike

Comment: Consider voting on the answers below, and [accepting the one that helped you most](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ).

Comment: hi, I've just signed up for tex stack exchange, lots of good answers, not sure how to vote yet, or if I have enough "reputation" to vote

Answer (score 6):

Macro `\logo` can be defined with an optional parameter that takes the options for `\includegraphics`:

```
\newcommand*{\logo}[2][]{%
  \gdef\@logo@params{#1}%
  \gdef\@logo{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\@logo@params}{}
\newcommand*{\@logo}{}
```

Usage for `\includegraphics`:

```
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\@logo@params]{\@logo}
```

The options need to be expanded first, because the syntax characters comma and equal sign for the key value list must not be hidden inside macros.

Example for `\logo`:

```
\logo[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}
```

Or

```
\logo[width=2cm, angle=90]{example-image-a}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
\newcommand{\logo}[2][]{%
  \gdef\make@logo{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\let\make@logo\relax
```

and use `\make@logo` at the point where you build the custom title, maybe like

```
\ifx\make@logo\relax
  % code for no logo, maybe nothing
\else
  % code before the logo, maybe \begin{center}
  \make@logo
  % code after the logo, maybe \end{center}
\fi
```

So if the document preamble using your style file has

```
\logo[scale=0.1]{file}
```

when the title is being typeset you'll get

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{file}
```

Without a `\logo` command, you'll get nothing.

The `\logo` command accepts, in its optional argument, any options valid for `\includegraphics`, so for instance

```
\logo[width=3cm]{file}
\logo[width=3cm,height=4cm,keepaspectratio]{file}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks, switching having the logo optional is what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

If `scale` is all you're after and you're comfortable with an interface like `\logo[0.7]{my-pic.png}`, then a simple `\newcommand` with optional parameter works:

```
\newcommand{\logo}[2][1]{\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}}
```

If you're not using the optional argument, it defaults to `1`.

Comment: I think one point is to define the logo with `\logo` in one place and to use it with `\@logo` in another, like `\author` or `\title`.

Comment: @gernot: All title content are typically stored and only expanded with `\maketitle`. So there's no real need to use both `\logo` and `\@logo` somewhere else. Moreover, it requires additional `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` delimiting (if not used inside a `.sty`).

Comment: How does one use your `\logo` command? How does one specify the image to be used, and how does `\maketitle` access it? In analogy to `\author` and `\title`, `\logo` should just store the image.

Comment: @gernot: You'd use `\title{...\logo[.7]{my-pic.png}...}` and then `\maketitle` in your document.

Comment: I'm including as per \author etc.. so that it gets 'built' by \maketitle, its just for a trivial style file, for some technical notes.

Comment: Ok, this is one design. From this point of view there is no need to separate title, author, date, logo, since one can stuff everything into a single command `\storecompletetitle`. But logically, the logo is at least as different from the title as the author or the date. My understanding of the original intention is that the goal is to have more categories of information that can be first filled and later used.